# Laravel Installation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have downloaded laravel from github. I also have composer installed. My problem is when i type in

```
composer install
```

[I got the following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXhd8.png) I can't fix it.

Comment: Hard to tell... Maybe composer might be outdated and cannot properly install newer Laravel. Try to run `composer self-update`

Comment: Though i said You are using the latest composer version. But it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the free laracasts series, this will guide you through the install - without any hiccups!

www.laracasts.com